# Access 2016 - Combo Box Selection

Tags: ms-access

when i select a client from my form, i have chosen an item description list. i was wondering how i would make it so that each record/client could have multiple items selected, so when a report is produced it will show the client with all the items for that record.

The steps i take are as follows:

Step one selecting the client through search and selecting the item

[image]

Step 2 saving the item and then open the quote for that record
enter image description here

[image]

Step 3 opening the quote report with the client details and the item info

[image]

Now these steps all work, i just need it so that when you select the client you may add multiple items to that record, so when saved the quote will load with multiple items on it.

Comment: This is a db design issue, not programming. Sounds like you need a related table.

Comment: what would you recommend? the current table ("job Listings") holds all the jobs that are made, i just need each job to hold multiple value/items of cost

Comment: Ive tried using multi values instead, it seems to be a better approach, as each job may then store multiple items.a few errors have occurred with the system through

Comment: I do not use multi-value fields. A multi-value field is really a related table - Access hides the table. What do you not understand about building a related table?

Comment: i agree a related table would be more suitable, i assume for it to collect the ID of the "project" then add the records for "Items"?